# Page shifts when jQueryUI dialog is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dialog

I sometimes observed the page shifting when opening a dialog.

```
<a class="myLink" href="javascript:void(0)">clickMe</a>
$("a.myLink").click(function(e) {$("#myDialog").dialog("open");});
```

A while back, I found that adding `return false;` in the click() callback fixed the behavior.

I just learned today that I should use `e.preventDefault();` instead.

So, I am going back to get rid of all my `return false;`statements, and I am starting to question whether I needed them in the first place.  Most times, I don't get the same behavior even without the `return false;`.  I don't know if it relates to the browser type or version, the jQuery version, the jQueryUI version, or my JavaScript.

I am starting to now believe/hope it only happens when the target is an anchor link, and what I think is happening is that when the dialog is opened, the default behavior of the link triggers and goes to the top of the page.  Is this correct, or is it causes by something else?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the jump only happens when a hash (such as #foobar) gets added to the url. You shouldn't blanket prevent default or return false, there's actually a reason to do it or not to do it.

Comment: Right off the bat, your example won't work because your link has an ID of myLink, but your jQuery is targeting links with a class of .myLink.  Yes, unless you prevent the default behaviour of "click on a link", your page will jump in these cases.

Comment: I used to use `#` instead of `javascript:void(0)`.  Was that why it used to happen, and it should not do so anymore?

Comment: @isotrope.  My bad.  Fixed.

Comment: @user1032531 Correct. using `href="javascript:void(0)"` will also prevent the jump because it doesn't add a hash to the url, however it does cause an ugly statusbar tooltip to show up in most browsers.

Comment: That "javascript:void(0)" just looks so dirty to me, for some reason. ;)

Comment: So, is `#` with `e.preventDefault()` better?

Comment: @user1032531  IMHO, definitely! Plus it can have a double-use. You can also extract the attribute as a value for something else.. like "which modal should I open?" based on href, etc.